# HMMT 2022 February Geometry Round Problem 1

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Consider the following problem (found [here](https://hmmt-archive.s3.amazonaws.com/tournaments/2022/feb/geo/solutions.pdf) along with the solutions):

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle with $\angle A=60^\circ$. Line $\ell$ intersects segments $AB$ and $AC$ and splits triangle $ABC$ into an equilateral triangle and quadrilateral. Let $X$ and $Y$ be on $\ell$ such that $BX$ and $CY$ are perpendicular to $\ell$. Given that $AB=20$ and $AC=22$ compute $XY$

Please post other solutions to this question. Here's what I did:

> Note that the segments $BX$ and $CY$ are variable. So we can set $BX=0$, then $CY>0$ because $AC>AB$. The large(st) equilateral triangle formed has sides of $20$ since $AB$ is one of its sides. Let the intersection of $\ell$ with $AC$ be denoted as $C'$. Then, $BC'=AB$. Also, $CC'=2$. We now need to find $C'Y$. Since  $\angle AC'B'=60^\circ$, $\angle CC'Y=60^\circ$, so $C'Y=1$. So the answer is $XY=BC'+C'Y=20+1=21$

Here is the original solution made by the competition organizers:

> Let the intersection points of $ℓ$ with $AB$ and $AC$ be $B′$ and $C
> ′$. Note that $AB′ + AC′ = 2B′C'$, $BB′ = 2XB′$, and $CC′ = 2YC′$. Adding gives us
> $AB + AC = AB′ + AC′ + BB′ + CC′ = 2(B′C′ + XB′ + Y C′) = 2XY$.
> Thus, $XY =\frac{20+22}2 = 21$.

Comment: Any reason why you didn't post the official solution (which is in the link)? That solution looks simple enough, so what else are you trying to ask for?

Comment: @CalvinLin Read the second to last question. I want to see other solutions.

Comment: IMO Any correct solution will essentially boil down the to equation that they wrote . You could express it with trigonometric terms if you don't recognize the ratio of sides. I don't think there is much more to it. $\quad$ What makes you think that there are other (distinct enough) solutions to this problem?

Comment: @CalvinLin But what makes you think that there are no distinct solutions to this problem? :) You have to prove that there aren't any other solutions

Comment: That's partly why I stated off with "In my opinion", since I'm also basing it on my experience/know-how. The crux of the problem is the length chasing argument expressed by the equation. There could be ways of disguising this, like doing the calculation on another constructed line, or breaking it up into different pieces, etc.

Comment: @CalvinLin I will post my old solution on the OP. What was wrong with it?

Comment: Like I stated, you only proved it for the particular case of $BX = 0$. You didn't show it for the general case. Hence, this is not a complete solution, even if it results in the correct numerical answer. EG How do you know that the answer isn't (say) $XY = 21+BX$? $\quad$ Note that  you could, very easily, adjust your proof to deal with the general case, so I encourage you to do so.

Comment: @CalvinLin What I was doing was to "slide" $\ell$ along $AB$ and $AC$, so $XY$ is preserved.

Comment: Great! So, "unslide" $l$ and then you will have a correct proof for the general case where $BX = x$.  OR, like you said, if you slide $l$ (with $BX=x$) to $l'$ (with $BX'=0$), then show that $XY = X'Y'$ , and hence we are done. Like I said, you could very easily adjust your proof to deal with the general case.

Comment: @CalvinLin Okay, thanks for your suggestion! I am re-writing my proof to fit the general case rn.

Comment: @CalvinLin as a proof sketch, we describe $XY$ as a line in the coordinate plane. Is that correct?

Comment: Setting $BX=0$ is a clever trick and does work for the contest, but for a general solution, you need to do it while preserving $BX$

Comment: Why is this question closed? My context is there. The problem's source is there. My try is there. What's wrong? None of the (at least) five closers even commented.